# opening multiple files in Intellij idea doesnot work using spawn on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, intellij-idea, child-process, spawn

im using this snippet, this works for all the editors expect Intellij idea. it always opens only the first file in the array.

```
const opts: SpawnOptions = {
detached: true
}
const paths = [file1Path, file2Path, file3Path]
paths.forEach((fullPath) => {
        spawn('open', ['-a', editorPath, fullPath], opts)
      });
```

tried it with exec in the following way and it works..but how do i make it possible for the child process to continue running after the parent exits(i'm using detached to make it possible)

`` exec(`open -a "${editorPath}" filepath1 filepath2 filePath3`) ``

expecting the reason why its not working for Intellij IDEA alone, and a workaround for this issue?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA launcher first starts the IDE instance and once it's started, running it again will just pass the arguments to the already running instance. It looks like when you start it in the loop, the first instance is not fully initialized to accept the arguments for the rest of the files.

Comment: @CrazyCoder tried the following way too no luck
```spawn('open', ['-a', editorPath, file1 file2 file3], opts)```